# The print statement I use is showing a syntax error, kindly note the error on my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Kindly look at 10th line of this code snippet:

[image]

Comment: you forgot to close the print statement, line 8 should be `print(txt.read())`

Comment: You shouldn't post images like that. Please put the code in the question.

Comment: @bichanna i'm a beginner , so hereafter i'll correct it..

Comment: What makes you think beginners should not read the documentation?

Comment: Syntax errors are frequently above the line referenced by python. Python tells you when its parser finally recognized that something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close `print()`:

```
print(txt.read())
```